# how to get a non NAT ip in Win 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ip, nat, ip-address

When ever I connect my internet thorough usb tethering or wifi hotspot or my router's wifi and check my ip through ipconfig, it always shows natted (NAT - network address translation) ip (192.168.xxx.xxx). How can I get a public ip instead of that natted one.

I am asking this question because I cant receive a reverse shell with the nat ip. I need my public ip.

Comment: The router gets the public IP. You need to configure it for port forwarding to be able to reach an internal computer. That essentially makes it non-portable.

Comment: can u suggest some resources or YouTube video, where the same problem has been resolved.

Comment: The problem cannot be solved if you don't have admin access to the router.

Comment: I have admin access. And if I use ethernet instead of wifi, and do an ipconfig, I got ipv4 address of 10.xx.xx.xx .

Comment: Then investigate how to set up port forwarding in your router's manual.